# Monitoring HP Proliant iLO whith perl script in Nagios

Tags: hp, perl, nagios, ilo

I'm trying to monitor an iLO with this script:

https://www.monitoringexchange.org/attachment/preview/Check-Plugins/Hardware/Server/HP-%2528Compaq%2529/check_ilo2_health/13-05-17_07-41-53_check_ilo2_health.pl

Everything seems to be OK, but if I put the -l option (enables log check), it only shows the older event of de iLO log, how can I change the script to show only de newer event log?

Thanks in advance.

Miguel

Comment: Easier to check from the host using the HP agents...

Comment: I don't know if possible to install HP agents on VMware ESX 5.1

Comment: It is possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're running VMware ESXi on HP ProLiant server hardware, your best bet is to install the HP CIM agents and utilities on the host to expose more detailed system health parameters to vSphere.

Which server model(s) are you using?

There are three components you need for an HP server running ESXi 5.1:

- The [HP ESXi offline bundle](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=4091432&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=idx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_77730c01570b47e9a20c330d24%257CswEnvOID%253D4141%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken).
- The [HP ESXi utilities bundle](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=4091432&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=idx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_bb349b2573c649549cb57109c9%257CswEnvOID%253D4141%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken).
- The [HP NMI sourcing driver](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=4091432&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=idx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_db35d0eeedfc4dc28ec19896da%257CswEnvOID%253D4141%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken).

These get downloaded to a datastore and installed with:

`esxcli software install vib /vmfs/volumes/datastore/<packagename>.vib`

There's also an [HP-specific build of ESXi](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?productId=285&downloadGroup=HP-ESXI-5.1.0-GA-10SEP2012) that has all of this built-in. But the above process can be applied to a standard vanilla ESXi installation.

Comment: The server model I'm using is: ProLiant BL460c G1:

Comment: Yeah, the same thing applies. But since this is a blade server, what specific information are you interested in obtaining? If I were you, I'd be pulling info from the chassis Onboard Administrator.

Comment: Health info like temperatures, fans, power, and the IML log.

Comment: For the BL460c there is only the ESXi offline bundle and the utilities bundle, there is no NMI sourcing driver

Comment: The packages I linked are all in the HP VMware build. It doesn't matter if the bl460c has it listed on its page or not. Install the versions I linked to.

Comment: Okay, tomorrow I will try it both on a test system. Thanks a lot